# Turning replace regex into java algorithm

Tags: java, regex, algorithm, performance

I have following java regex replace logic

```
text.replaceAll("(?i)(" + keyword + ")(?!([^<]+)?>>)", "<b>$1</b>");
```

What it does it takes `keyword` and looks for it on HTML page while ignoring the case and content of HTML tags. Than it captures the found keyword and surrounds it with `<b></b>` tags.

How should I do this with use of `StringBuilder` or `StringBuffer`, possibly `HashMap`? The goal is better performance.

## UPDATE

I crated following method using the new [commons lang 3 beta package](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-3.0-beta/index.html):

```
public static String highlight(String text, String q) {
    String[] textAr = StringUtils.split(text, " ");
    int len = textAr.length;
    int index = 0;
    while (index < len){
         if (textAr[index].startsWith("<")) {
            while (!textAr[index].endsWith(">")) {
                index++;
            }
         }
         if (StringUtils.equalsIgnoreCase(textAr[index], q)){

             textAr[index] = "<b>"+textAr[index]+"</b>";
         }
         index++;
    }
    return StringUtils.join(textAr," ");
}
```

After running couple of tests I got about 10% performance increase from above solution. Any suggestion on how to make it better WITHOUT Regex would be appreciated.

Comment: Pardon my nagging, but 'do not parse html with regex' is one of the most frequent recommendations on SO. You can find lots of relevant answers where highest-rated SO users stress this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I agree with Nikita: the best way to parse HTML is using HTML or XML parser.

But if you really need this here are some tips.

1. string buffer is a thread safe version of string builder, so if you do not have to be thread safe or if problems of thread safity are solved by other layer use string builder.
2. StringBuilder does not support replace using Patterns. Strings do support. But working directly with strings when number of keywords is high is ineffective.
3. So, the most effective way is to generate pattern that contains all keywords and then perform replace operation once. For example if you have keywords foo, bar, tar, create regex like 
   `regex = (?i)(foo|bar|tar)(?!([^<]+)?>>)`

Now run `text.replaceAll(regex);`

You can use StringBuilder when creating the regex but I'd recommend you to use
`StringUtils.join()` from jakarta utils or similar utility from Guava.

Comment: you can't parse html with an xml parser, since html is not xml (unless it's also xhtml).

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to escape the keyword just in case:

```
Pattern p = text.replaceAll("(?i)(" + Pattern.quote(keyword) + ")(?!([^<]+)?>>)", "<b>$1</b>");
```

Then you need to create a matcher

```
Matcher m = p.matcher(myInputString);
```

If the input doesn't match, then you're done:

```
if (!m.find()) { return myInputString; }
```

Otherwise allocate an output buffer:

```
StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder(myInputString.length() + 16);
```

and mark all occurrences of the keyword bold:

```
int nCharsProcessed = 0;
do {
  out.append(myInputString, nCharsProcessed, m.start(1))
     .append("<b>")
     .append(m.group(1))
     .append("</b>");
  nCharsProcessed = m.end(1);
} while (m.find());
```

and finally, concatenate the portion after the last match and return

```
out.append(myInputString, nCharsProcessed, myInputString.length());
return out.toString();
```

Answer (score 1):

<del>replaceAll already works with StringBuffers anyway. (Well, to be precise, Matcher.replaceAll() uses StringBuffer, but String.replaceAll only delegates to Matcher.replaceAll() )</del>

For better performance you could build up the regex String by using a StringBuffer:

```
    String head = "(?i)(";
    String tail = ")(?!([^<]+)?>>)";

    StringBuffer regex = new StringBuffer();
    regex.append(head);
    regex.append(keyword);
    regex.append(tail);

    text.replaceAll(regex.toString(), "<b>$1</b>");
```

I don't really know, if there is a faster Replacement Implementation than the one of the Matcher class. But before you implement it yourself by using StringBuffer, I wanted to tell you, that it's already implemented that way.

The following pseudocode might be buggy, but you could try it like this. (better performance is not guaranteed, but this should be the same as above without regex)

```
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(text);

int i = 0;
int size = text.size()
while(i<size) {
    if(sb.charAt(i) == '<') {
        increase i until you find '>';
    }
    if(sb.charAt(i) == keyword.charAt(0) {
        if(next chars of sb match next chars of keyword) {
            insert "<b>" before and "</b>" after the keyword;
            size += 7;
            i += keyword.size() + 7;
        }
    }
}
```

you might also want to take a look into the Matcher implementation of replaceAll: http://kickjava.com/src/java/util/regex/Matcher.java.htm

Comment: This should be really helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2861/options-for-html-scraping

Answer (score 1):

Split on the keyword then concat everything in a StringBuffer

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;


class Hilighter {

        public static String regex(String text, String key) {
                System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis());
                text = text.replaceAll("(?i)(" + key + ")(?!([^<]+)?>>)", "<b>$1</b>");
                System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis());
                return text;
        }


        public static String splitr(String text, String key) {
                System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis());
                String[] parts = text.split(key);
                StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
                buffer.append(parts[0]);
                for (int i = 1; i < parts.length; i++) {
                        buffer.append("<b>");
                        buffer.append(key);
                        buffer.append("</b>");
                        buffer.append(parts[i]);
                }
                System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis());
                return buffer.toString();
        }


        public static void main(String[] args) {
                try {
                        String text = readFileAsString("./test.html");
                        text = splitr(text, args[0]);
                        text = regex(text, args[0]);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                        System.err.println("IO ERROR");
                }
        }


        private static String readFileAsString(String filePath) throws java.io.IOException{
                StringBuffer fileData = new StringBuffer(1000);
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath));
                char[] buf = new char[1024];
                int numRead=0;
                while((numRead=reader.read(buf)) != -1){
                    String readData = String.valueOf(buf, 0, numRead);
                    fileData.append(readData);
                    buf = new char[1024];
                }
                reader.close();
                return fileData.toString();
        }



}
```

Comment: You mean StringBuilder, not StringBuffer.  StringBuffer adds unnecessary synchronization; which isn't needed in a single method.

Comment: @Mat Banik thats right; btw, it was not clear in your question that you cannot use regexes, just you need better performance.

Comment: @Mat Banik ok; you can replace String.split with StringUtils.splitByWholeSeparator from commons-lang [ http://libcommons-lang-java.sourcearchive.com/documentation/2.3-4/classorg_1_1apache_1_1commons_1_1lang_1_1StringUtils_13d2bd973a0228f624e30d8ae46ef80d.html#13d2bd973a0228f624e30d8ae46ef80d ]

Comment: yup i've seen it; that way you tokenize all words, for a reasonable input file you will get a very big array and a lot of iterations; moreover you risk to hilight words in tag element attributes value (<a title="bla bla keyword bla">). What i suggest is to split over some more interesting character, ie "<". foreach iteration if (!element.endsWith(">")) { search&hilite keyword }

Answer (score 1):

Note that split() also uses regular expressions.  If you truly need something that has to nothing to do with regular expressions, you are left looping through the string yourself.  Or using indexOf() to find the first match and then see if it is followed by a less than sign.

I don't think you mean that regular expressions can't be used literally though.  I think you mean Patterns shouldn't be used directly.